# Turtlebot Purchasing Options

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those of us who already have a few Roombas and Kinects lying around, is there going to be an option to buy some of the hardware from Turtlebot independently from the whole kit?

I am mainly interested in purchasing the IMU and the shelving "stack" that comes with the Turtlebot kit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10009/turtlebot-purchasing-options/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-05-20

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We [decided](http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2011/05/20/turtlebot-going-open-source) to make the TurtleBot hardware open source.  We're working on posting the docs and linking to suppliers for all the parts, including the shelving stack and gyro/power board.  So you will be able to buy them separately.  Check back soon at [turtlebot.com](http://turtlebot.com).

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

From its [website](http://www.willowgarage.com/turtlebot/order), I understand there are two purchasing options:

---

### Core Kit $499.99

*If you already have an iRobot Create and laptop.*

- USB Communications Cable
- TurtleBot Power and Sensor Board
- TurtleBot Power and Sensor Board

- TurtleBot Hardware
- Microsoft Kinect
- TurtleBot to Kinect Power Cable
- USB Stick TurtleBot Installer

### Complete Kit $1199.99

*Everything you need to get started with a TurtleBot.*

- TurtleBot Core Kit (see above)

- iRobot Create Robot
- 3000 mAh Ni-MH Battery
- Fast Charger
- Asus EeePC 1215N

---

Maybe there is a third option where we can skip the kinect?

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-16**:
We'll have a European version of the turtlebot out soon on turtlebot.eu where you can buy it without the kinect, with different accessories.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-22**:
And it appears that the design has been open sourced!

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-21**:
I like your answer, but I'm going to wait on someone from WG to weight in on the non-Kinect option to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to the TurtleBot folks showing things off at Robogames 2011, there are a half dozen turtlebots in various stages of construction in the SoCAL robotics group.  Here is an image of the bottom turtlebot deck that we are working with:
[image description http://profmason.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/turtlebotlayout.jpg](http://profmason.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/turtlebotlayout.jpg) Each of the subsequent decks are the same but only uses the four larger holes. Construction drawings, autocad files for your laser cutter and tips are at:  http://profmason.com/?p=1590
Here is the Gyro setup:
http://profmason.com/?p=1591

---

Originally posted by [profmason](https://answers.ros.org/users/583/profmason/) with karma: 21 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We are working on gettig a turtlebot shop specialized for Europe online: [www.turtlebot.eu](http://www.turtlebot.eu)

We will propose different kinds of kit (Complete, Core...), and "a la carte" configurations to match any specific needs.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been anxiously waiting for TurtleBot since it's announcement... I'm disappointed, though, in the pricing.  Parts seem a little expensive:  $99.95 for the standoff kit!?!?!  This is not a PR2!

There is sooo much good coming out of Willowgarage.  ROS is amazing.  The interest in sharing so much information is astounding to me.  All of that has been truly a turning point.  But Sheez...  if Turtlebot is supposed to be an affordable way to gain entry into the field, how does one justify $99.95 for a handful of parts I should be able to duplicate by visiting my local hardware store?

-Mike

---

Originally posted by [mbahr](https://answers.ros.org/users/106/mbahr/) with karma: 31 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-06-30**:
Our prices are still undergoing review but we try to provide cheap alternatives for trays. We have MDF trays starting from 21 euros. Visit http://www.turtlebot.eu for more information.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-20**:
Make them cheaper and we'll post it on turtlebot.com. We put a call out to anyone who was interested in making TurtleBot parts and these are the prices people came back with. If you can make it cheaper, we welcome you to make them and post them for sale.